# jQuery - Moving a div to the top of it's parent

Tags: jquery

I've got a script where if a div exists I want to be at the top of it's parent div. Here's what I tried:

```
        if ($(".pane-bundle-hblock .field-name-field-hblock-image-right").length){
            $(".pane-bundle-hblock .field-name-field-hblock-image-right").parent().prepend($('this'));
        }
```

What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`$('this')` selects `<this></this>` elements.

I would do something like this:

```
$(".pane-bundle-hblock .field-name-field-hblock-image-right").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

If the element doesn't exist, the `.each()` won't have anything to iterate over, so you don't really need to check to see if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that 'this' has any special context within the conditional statement.  You may want to be more explicit in what you're moving:

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/BKg6z/

```
if ($(".pane-bundle-hblock .field-name-field-hblock-image-right").length){
    $(".pane-bundle-hblock .field-name-field-hblock-image-right").parent().prepend($(".pane-bundle-hblock .field-name-field-hblock-image-right"));
}
```